# Gravatar not showing when calling users details

Tags: gravatar

I am pulling out users details from a custom role I have created which works great apart from the avatar. It did flash up and then refreshed disappeared again which is odd in itself... I can see the Gravatar in the users profile so I know it exists.

My code is looking like the following:

```
<?php
    $consultants = get_users( 'role=consultant&number=2' );
    // Array of WP_User objects.
    foreach ( $consultants as $consultant ) {
        echo '<div class="columns six consultantCard">';

            echo '<div class="row">';

            echo '<div class="columns four">';
            echo '<span class="avatar">' . get_avatar($consultant->$user_email, 150) . '</span>';
            echo '</div>';

            echo '<div class="columns eight">';
            // Get users details
            echo '<span class="name">' . esc_html( $consultant->first_name ) . ' ' . esc_html( $consultant->last_name ) . '</span>';
            echo '<span class="jobTitle">' . esc_html( $consultant->job_title ) . '</span>';
            echo '<span class="location">Currently based in ' . esc_html( $consultant->current_location ) . '</span>';

            // Check if user is less than 30 days old
            if( strtotime($consultant->user_registered) < strtotime('30 days') ){   
                echo '<span class="newTag">New</span>'; 
            }

            // Check if user is featured
            if($consultant->featured == 'Yes'){
                echo '<span class="featuredTag">Featured Candiate</span>';
            }           

            // Check if user is accredited
            if($consultant->accredited == 'Yes'){ ?>
                <span class="icon"><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/assets/img/icons/accreditedIcon.png" /></span>
                <?php echo '<span class="accreditedTag">Bench Accredited</span>';
            }
            echo '</div>';  
            echo '</div>';  

        echo '<hr />';  
        echo '</div>';      
    }
?>
```

It just gives me the default grey image...?